# Having trouble solving implicit function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

$$ x\cos y + y\cos u + u\cos x = 1 $$

I'm trying to calculate u$'_x$ and $u'_y$ in the point $(0,1)$
while $0 \leq u \leq \pi$.

I've managed to find:

$$u'_x = - \frac{\cos y-u\sin x}{\cos x-y\sin u}\\
u'_y = - \frac{\cos u-x\sin y}{\cos x-y\sin u}$$

What holds me back currently I can't find $u$.

I get to this equation when I place $(0,1)$ ---->  $ \cos u + u = 1$

Thanks in advance, hope this question isn't too dumb.

Comment: Drawing the graphs of $u\mapsto\cos u$ and $u\mapsto 1-u$ you can see that necessarily $u=0$ at the point in question.

Comment: note: $\cos u<1-u, 0<u\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\cos 0=1-0$. See the desmos [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ikyov0goat).